# Limit number of results using column value as a count

Tags: php, mysql

I have two queries, one which will get a list of IDs from the main table, and another which will get all records in another table that relate to that ID.

I'd like to split it into pages of results, but my google searches are only coming up with people who want to have a certain number of results per column value, not who want to limit the overall count by it.

The main table has a column that contains the number of records, so actually reading the other table isn't needed. The limit would be used as a minimum value, so if there are still records left in the current group after the limit, it'll continue displaying them. That'd be somehow calculated as part of the offset so it can start in the correct place.

Here's an example of what I mean:

Table 1:

```
ID | Records
1  |    2
2  |    3
3  |    28
4  |    7
...
```

Table 2 (contents don't need to be known for this question):

```
ID | GroupID | Value
1  |    1    |   x
2  |    1    |   x
3  |    2    |   x
4  |    2    |   x
5  |    2    |   x
6  |    3    |   x
   ...
```

If the limit was given as 3 for example, both `1` and `2` should display on the first page, since just `1` by itself is under the limit. The next page will then start on `3`, and that'll take up the entire page.

I could just manually count up using PHP until I reach the limit, though it might end up going slow if there were a lot of pages (I've no idea if mysql would be any better in that regard though). Here's a quick example of how that'd work to get the offset:

```
$page = 2;
$limit = 40;

$count = 0;
$current_page = 1;

$query = 'SELECT ID, Records FROM table1';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $count += $row['Records'];
    if($count > $limit){
        $current_page ++;
        $count = 0;
        if($current_page == $page){
            $start_id = $row['ID'];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't explain the usage of *Table 2*. Is it even relevant with respect to your question? Or, you're planning to do everything with *Table 1* since you said *The main table has a column that contains the number of records, so actually reading the other table isn't needed.*?

Comment: Yeah, table 2 isn't particularly relevant to the question, I just included it for visual purposes in case I hadn't explained it well enough :)

Comment: I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: How big is `table1` going to be?

Comment: I think for a small scale site it may get up to a few hundred per month, I had something similar on my old site and there's around 10k records or something, still out though so can't check the actual amount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated:

A "custom" [**Pagination**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination) is what you're looking for. So if you're planning to hop from page to page, you can't use hardcoded `$page` and `$current_page` values. Those values should be generated dynamically once you're on a particular page. In fact, you should have the *ID* column value in the query part of the URL so that the pagination links could satisfy your business logic.

Assuming the fact that your *ID* column value starts from `1`, your code should be like this:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 1;
$limit = 40;

// Display query results based on particular ID number
$query = 'SELECT ID, Records FROM table1 WHERE ID >= ' . $id;
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();
if($rowCount){
    $total = 0;
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        if($total <= $limit){
            $total += $row['Records'];
            // Display $row details here
        }else{
            // Get the next $id value
            $id = $row['ID'];
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Display relevant ID links
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table1';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

$idArr = array();
$total = 0;
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if($total == 0){
        $idArr[] = $row['ID'];
    }
    if($total <= $limit){
        $total += $row['Records'];
    }else{
        $total = 0;
    }
}

foreach($idArr as $idValue){
    if($idValue == $id){
        echo '<a>'.$idValue.'</a> ';
    }else{
        echo '<a href="?id='.$idValue.'">'.$idValue.'</a> ';
    }
}
```

---

**Sidenote:** If the *ID* column value of your table doesn't start from `1`, then use a separate query to get the first *ID* value and update the following statement,

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : <FIRST_ID_VALUE>;
```

Comment: Thanks, though unless I've misunderstood your script, I don't it quite does what I'm after. For example, using your limit of 40, if ID `1` has 20 records, and ID `2` contains 25 records, page 1 should only display `1` and `2`, not `1` to `40`. I'll give you the actual link in a second so you might see a bit better, cheers anyway

Comment: So, I have working pagination here: https://peterdev.huntvfx.uk/stats/pages, but the same method won't work for this: https://peterdev.huntvfx.uk/stats/sessions (for the record, it isn't for anything important, I just wanted to try display the tracking stuff)

Comment: Sorry, that's kind of why I included the second table, here's a more drawn out way, hopefully it makes it clearer: http://pastebin.com/NdYTmuXj

Comment: @Peter I think I understood your problem clearly. I've completely updated my answer. Please test your application with the updated code snippet.

Comment: Thanks, that looks a bit more like it haha, I've gotta set off in a minute though so I'll test it out after I'm back :)

Comment: I just tested it out and it almost works fine, but there's a bug that I can't figure how to fix. Here's the first 13 records for an example: http://pastebin.com/wV1AcHAm. Basically, each ID from yours is incremented by 1, so the pages result as `1-6`, `8-13`, `15-25`, `27-29`, whereas they should be `1-6`, `7-12`, `13-23`.

Comment: However I get the idea behind it I think, and can probably adapt it with my code if you're not able to think of a fix, I know it's a bit difficult to test without access to the database :P

Comment: I just benchmarked it out of curiosity, yours is roughly 2.0 - 2.5 times slower, but the difference is like 0.04 seconds at 20k records so not really a problem. I'm just thinking I may have to generate that list on each page load, as I'd prefer to use the page number and not the current ID

Comment: @Peter Great to see your issue is resolved now. Cheers! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to create the "Next" button, you could try this way:

```
select t1.ID, t1.Records
from table1 t1
left join table1 t2
    on  t2.ID < t1.ID
    and t2.ID > :last_selected_id_1
where t1.ID > :last_selected_id_2
group by t1.ID, t1.Records
having coalesce(sum(t2.Records), 0) < :limit
order by t1.ID
```

`:last_selected_id_x` is the last ID from the current page or `0` for the first page.

http://rextester.com/FJRUV28068

You can use MySQL session variables to create page links:

```
select page, min(ID) as min_id, max(ID) as max_id
from (
    select ID
         , @page := case when @sum = 0 then @page + 1 else @page end as page
         , @sum  := case when (@sum + Records) >= :limit
             then 0 
             else @sum + Records
         end as sum
    from table1
    cross join (select @sum := 0, @page := 0) initvars
    order by ID
) sub
group by page
```

The result would look like:

```
page | min_id | max_id
   1 |      1 |      2
   2 |      3 |      3 
   3 |      4 |      4
```

http://rextester.com/LQVJWP18655

Note that it is officially (as of documentation) not recomended to use the session variables like that (read and write in one statement). Feature versions may break your code.

Comment: Ah thanks, I take it this is similar to how endless loading works? For the current purpose I could do with defining the page numbers, but in the future I may try switch over :)

Comment: Yes, that should also work for a infinite scroll. The problem with page numbers in your case, is that you have to iterate over all rows in the table. They can not be just "calculated".

Comment: Yeah I was hoping that there'd be some fancy mysql function that'd have that feature inbuilt haha. I tested out calculating every page on 20k records and it took about 0.05 seconds, so that by itself isn't so bad, I quite like the idea of yours though so I'll definitely check it out after getting the basics working correctly. Just a quick question though, you have `last_selected_id` 1 and 2, did you mean to have them as the same value, like in your test?

Comment: `:last_selected_id_1` and `:last_selected_id_2` is the same value (PDO seems not to allow the same parameter to be used twice). BTW creating page numbers could be done faster in MySQL using session variables. But it would still be a full table scan

Comment: Ah thanks, that's interesting to see it done like that, I've stuck with PHP for now though so that I'm actually able to understand it haha. I've just spent the past few hours getting my own version up and running, also I didn't realise to start with and couldn't figure why it wasn't working correctly, but the min/max ID idea didn't work when sorting the table by the last activity. I'll probably choose the other answer as I kinda based mine of his, but thanks a bunch for this too, like I said I'll probably visit back later down the line when I want to learn more advanced stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the result I ended up with, I ended up basing it off Rajdeeps answer but tweaked so that it'll allow sorting.

```
$query = 'SELECT ID, Records FROM table1 ORDER BY something';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$id_array = array(); // For storing each ID
$current_ids = array(); // For storing the current ID pages
$initial_ids = array(); // For storing the first page, in case the page is too high

$count = 0;
$current_page = 1;
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $already_reset = false;

    // Move the session to the next page if it's more over the limit than under
    // For example, if a limit of 10 has 6 records already, and the next ID is 9 records, then start a new page
    if($id_array and $count + $row['Records'] / 2 > $max_links){
        array_push($id_array, $last_id);
        $current_page ++;
        $count = 0;
        $already_reset = true; // Set a marker so that if this ID is larger than the limit then don't start a 2nd new page
    }

    // Backup the first results in case page is too high and needs to be reset to 1
    if($current_page == 1){
        array_push($initial_ids, $row['ID']);
    }

    $count += $row['Records'];

    // The values that appear here are the results for the selected page
    // They may not be in sequence so store the individual IDs
    if($_GET['page'] == $current_page){
        array_push($current_ids, $row['ID']);
    }

    // Start a new page if over the limit
    if($count > $max_links and !$already_reset){
        $current_page ++;
        $count = 0;
        array_push($id_array, $row['ID']);
    }
    $last_id = $row['ID'];
}
array_push($id_array, $last_id);
$total_pages = count($id_array);

// If page is invalid revert to default
if(!$current_ids){
    $current_ids = $initial_ids;
    $_GET['page'] = 1;
}

$_GET['page'] = max(1, min($total_pages, intval($_GET['page'])));
```

`$current_ids` is an array of the IDs for the current page, and `$total_pages` is pretty self explanatory.